# calculating logarithmic equation: $64n\log_2(n)<8n^2$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I have an equation , which is like this $64n\log n < 8n^2$ . (the base of logarithm is 2) 
I know how to solve the logarithmic equations  . I am a programmer , so I wrote a simple program and answer is 44 . 
my tries , all end up here : 
$8\log_2(n) < n \Longrightarrow n^8 < 2^n \Longrightarrow n^8 - 2^n < 0$ , and here is where I can't solve the problem ! I think I am too close , but does not have any clue how to reach 44 ...

Comment: There is no closed form for the solution of $64 n \log_2 n = 8 n^2$, but one can write the solution using the special Lambert W function, or solve it numerically, e.g, using Newton's Method. One can see by hand that the solution is greater than $2^5$ but less than $2^6$.

Comment: @Travis  and I am really trying hard to learn math , which I was never good at it . can you provide a more detailed answer?

Comment: This equation has two solutions, namely
$n = 1.0999970302376...$ and $n=43.55926043688...$, but as Travis said they cannot be expressed by means of the most common elementary functions. In this case one can employ one of the several [numerical methods](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Numerical_Methods/Equation_Solving) for finding an approximate solution of a generic equation.

Comment: @shayan In short there's no way to do this by hand, and for most purposes  one has to content themselves with numerical approximations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry to disappoint you, but one cannot solve an inequality with complex numbers, as my solution will most likely be:

$$64n\log_2(n)=8n^2$$

$$8\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(2)}=n$$

$$\ln(n)=\frac{n\ln(2)}{8}$$

$$n=e^{\frac{n\ln(2)}{8}}$$

$$ne^{-\frac{n\ln(2)}{8}}=1$$

Multiply both sides by $-\frac{\ln(2)}{8}$:

$$-\frac{n\ln(2)}{8}e^{-\frac{n\ln(2)}{8}}=-\frac{\ln(2)}{8}$$

$$-\frac{n\ln(2)}{8}=W_k\left(-\frac{\ln(2)}{8}\right)$$

$$n=\frac{W_k\left(-\frac{\ln(2)}{8}\right)}{-\frac{\ln(2)}{8}}=e^{-W_k\left(-\frac{\ln(2)}{8}\right)}$$

If we have $k=0$, the primary branch, we may get a real solution.  Other branches will most likely be complex.